# Multiple domain names on same VPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, vps

I have a a2hosting VPS server with the following ip address: 67.209.122.170.
I have two godaddy domain names for my two websites - greenlemonevents.com and downloadexplore.com.

I have hosted my two nodejs applications on the remote server with different ports and i have updated DNS of both the domain names on godaddy to point to 67.209.122.170 , and I am using nginx as the web server to reverse proxy. I changed the following code in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.greenlemonevents.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://67.209.122.170:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.downloadexplore.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://67.209.122.170:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Here Greenlemonevents is running ok but when i open downloadexplore.com it opens greenlemonevents.com.

Comment: The second `server` block will respond to `www.downloadexplore.com` only. The first `server` block will respond to all other names including `downloadexplore.com`. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Even 2nd block is not responding to www.downloadexplore.com.
It is showing server error, while the site is accessible at downloadexplore.com:8080